Why do I get an UnexpectedRequestError (<PreparedRequest [GET]>, None) when trying to use the SmartSheet API?
I want to list the columns of a sheet so I know how columns are referenced vs how they appear in the smarsheet but I keep getting this error.
UnexpectedRequestError (<PreparedRequest [GET]>, None) at action = client.Sheets.get_columns(sID, include_all=True)
I am using VScode and python 3.7 since this is what my work allows.
I installed the VScode extensions Python, Jupyter and Intellicode.
I also had to run pip install urllib3==1.26.6 to deal with another error.
I am not sure if the error is in the code or how I set-up VScode and am new to API entirely.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Here is what I have tried so far.
import smartsheet as ss
import os
import logging

# specify access token --unique for each user
os.environ['SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN'] = xxxx

# client obj must point to .__gov_base__
client = ss.Smartsheet(api_base=ss.__gov_base__)

# set logger to critical events
logging.getLogger('smartsheet').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

# raise exceptions for API errors
client.errors_as_exceptions(True)

# define sheet ID
sID = xxx

action = client.Sheets.get_columns(sID, include_all=True)
columns = action.data
#print(f"Data has been saved to {csv_file}")
for col in columns:
    print(col.id)
    print(col.title)
    print('')

I used to receive this ImportError! Could not load api or model class __iter__ in addtion to the error when I used the code below to try and get more information, but now I do not see that as part of the error.
try:
    action = client.Sheets.get_columns(sID, include_all=True)
    print(action)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

I expect the code to simply print all of the column ids and titles but I have not been able to get it to work at all.
UPDATE
I have updated my code to this:
import smartsheet as ss
import os
import logging

# specify access token --unique for each user
os.environ['SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN'] = xxx

# client obj must point to .__gov_base__
sh = ss.Smartsheet(api_base=ss.__gov_base__)

# set logger to critical events
logging.getLogger('smartsheet').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

# raise exceptions for API errors
sh.errors_as_exceptions(True)

# define sheet ID
sID = xxx

try:
    action = sh.Sheets.get_columns(sID, include_all=True)
    print(action)
    columns = action.data
#print(f"Data has been saved to {csv_file}")
    for col in columns:
        print(col.id)
        print(col.title)
        print('')
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

I now receive a 403 forbidden error:
(<PreparedRequest [GET]>, None)
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.smartsheetgov.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2.0/sheets/xxx/columns?includeAll=True (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.smartsheetgov.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2.0/sheets/xxx/columns?includeAll=True (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "C:\...\ss_fetch.py", line 22, in <module>
    action = sh.Sheets.get_columns(sID, include_all=True)
smartsheet.exceptions.UnexpectedRequestError: (<PreparedRequest [GET]>, None)

I receive the same error whether I use the standard or gov API. I alos reached out to my work and they confirmed that the issue is on smartsheets side and to contact them.
I contacted smartsheets and they have not been able to ID the cause of the 403 error.
Any ideas what I have done incorrectly?
SOLVED
Smartsheets has a poorly written security certificate and we had to adjust how our proxies interact with their cert.

The root cause is the top line: the connection failed because of a 403 Forbidden response.  Something has gone wrong with your validation.

Thank you @TimRoberts. I think my only option at this point is to wait to hear back from Smartsheets.
